# Missing memory while profiling

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, profiling

I am using heapy memory profiler to figure out the memory bloat that happens in my python program. As you can see in the timeline below, the amount of memory between t1 and t2 in timeline, grows around 20 MB based on what task manager reports, but only 1.6 MB based on heapy. Where is the rest of the memory ? Does this indicate fragmentation ? How can I verify which object (for example CloudEntry) is causing fragmentation ?

Timeline:

t1 (**66 MB** private bytes task manager)

```
hpy().setrelheap()
// program runs ... 
// ...
// ..
// .
```

t2 (**86 MB** in private bytes task manager):

```
Partition of a set of 21897 objects. Total size = 1868016 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0    926   4   485224  26    485224  26 dict of common.cloud_entry.CloudEntry
     1   5564  25   431040  23    916264  49 str
     2   1888   9   219008  12   1135272  61 __builtin__.set
     3    388   2   203312  11   1338584  72 dict of Queue.Queue
     4   1164   5   162960   9   1501544  80 dict of threading._Condition
     5   2328  11    83808   4   1585352  85 types.BuiltinFunctionType
     6   4561  21    54732   3   1640084  88 int
     7   1172   5    44688   2   1684772  90 list
     8   1164   5    37248   2   1722020  92 threading._Condition
     9    926   4    29632   2   1751652  94 common.cloud_entry.CloudEntry
<64 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```